# Xamarin notification

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification

I'm developing a Xamarin Cross platform app and I need to send notifications dynamically using xamarin code.

I tried with Firebase but not works.

How can I do it simple using my server?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging should do the trick for you. I recently did that and got it working fine without any issues. It has been documented with step by step procedure in the below articles. Please refer to them and let me know it helps.

https://xmonkeys360.com/2019/12/08/xamarin-forms-fcm-setup-configuration-part-i/ 
https://xmonkeys360.com/2019/12/09/fcm-configuration-in-xamarin-forms-part-ii/

Comment: Hi, The second link will be https://xmonkeys360.com/2019/12/09/fcm-configuration-in-xamarin-forms-part-ii/